# Servicio de Apache 2.4 se detiene

Tags: php, apache, xampp, http

Tengo un problema al momento de iniciar Apache y es que es detenido inesperadamente por el windows.

Ya realicé el cambio de puertos 80 (probe colocarlo en 50 o 8080, no obteniendo resultados), desactivé y activé de nuevo los ISS del windows pero aun así nada. Este error no solo me pasa en XAMPP, sino también en otros programas como MAMP y WampServer.

PD: Por alguna razón, solo me ocurre esto con las versiones de PHP 7.4 para arriba, ya que con las versiones 7.3 para abajo apache si quiere inicializar.

Ayuda por favor . Adjunto el error:

12:58:18  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...

12:58:19  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

12:58:19  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped

12:58:19  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

12:58:19  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

12:58:19  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

12:58:19  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

12:58:19  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

12:58:19  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this

12:58:19  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

EDIT: error.log de apache

[Thu Sep 09 00:08:48.020164 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6828:tid 640] AH01909: [www.example.com:4433:0](http://www.example.com:4433:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 09 00:08:48.171524 2021] [core:warn] [pid 6828:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Sep 09 00:08:48.183518 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6828:tid 640] AH01909: [www.example.com:4433:0](http://www.example.com:4433:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Sep 09 00:08:48.187515 2021] [:emerg] [pid 6828:tid 640] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting

Comment: ¿Seguiste las instrucciones del mensaje?

Comment: Si. Ya analicé todo antes de venir a preguntar aquí. Bueno, creo

Comment: ¿Qué dicen el log y el visor de eventos? Agrégalos a la pregunta.

Comment: Listo, añadido.

Comment: Intenta instalar una version mas reciente de vcredist

Comment: Si era eso, tenía la versión anterior (parece) al vcredist jajaja Gracias!!